# How can I loop same TestNG test multiple times (including BeforeClass and AfterClass)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I know about `invocationCount=10` parameter of the `@Test` annotation.

But the problem is - if one of my tests fails, then all the rest of the tests fail as well.
How I can run same `@Test` 10 times (including `BeforeClass` and `AfterClass`) for every run.
Does every run start as a new run in this case?

Because otherwise if I do `invocationCount=100`, and if fails at 5th test, then it will fail all the rest 95 tests.

Comment: Use a factory to create separate tests. Create a for loop and return an object array of test objects... http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories

Comment: @Grasshopper I can see you coming up with brilliant ideas why don't you convert those `Comments` into `Answers` :) Thanks